# Django form ignore validations on save vs submit

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a Django form in which the user will have two options

1. Save the form (temporarily)
2. Submit the form

What I am trying to do is to allow the users to save the form temporarily and after they have all the data they can come back, edit the form and make the final submission.
The problem is that the form validation will not allow partially filled form to be saved.
Is there any way I can ignore validations when "Save" is pressed whereas perform all the validations when "Submit" is pressed?

I do not want to have 2 views. I want the same view with two buttons "Save" and "Submit" if Save is pressed some of the validations will be ignored (i.e. required field left empty due to the fact that the user might not currently have the information).  But if the "Submit" is pressed, all the date should be validated.

Please note that all the validations takes place backend with Django.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can add `blank=True` to every field in your model.

Comment: @Danny all the fields are blank=True in order to allow saving, but if the user "Submit" the form them I have to perform all the form validations backend side in order to make sure that required fields are not left empty.  That's my main issue, i.e. perform different validations if "Save" is pressed and different validations when "Submit" is pressed